# How to delete certain pixels in a rectangle

Tags: c#, image

I am designing a space invaders game and I need to make the barriers break from where they were hit like the original game, As of now my barrier just shrinks:

```
for (int r = 0; r < BarrierXPos.Count; r++) {
    if (CollisionCheck("Barrier", BarrierXPos[r], BarrierYPos[r], null) == true)
        {
            BarrierFactor[r] += 1;
        }
    }

for (int x = 0; x < BarrierXPos.Count; x++)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, (int)BarrierXPos[x],       (int)BarrierYPos[x], 100 - (10 * BarrierFactor[x]), 50);

    }
```

So as of now the size is determined by the amount of times the block has been hit. However I want it to be more like the original space invaders and would like the block to be dynamically broken from where it was hit. What I am wondering is how I can determine the pixels in which the bullet hits the barrier bitmap and subsequently remove them.

Comment: I've just been researching at this point I know how to change a certain pixel in a bitmap but not large amounts of them

Comment: As these are vector drawings, switch from rectangle to polygon or path (polygon is faster, path provides some advanced features).  `e.Graphics.DrawPolygon`.  Then when your polygon is hit, insert a new point (or points) to "chip away" at the polygon.  when the surface area of the polygon is small enough just destroy it.

Comment: @SamAxe The `DrawPolygon` function takes an array of `Point`s. Converting a rectangle to `Point[]` is trivial, but altering that array further to "drop" specific points within requires more thinking. First, you must define the manner of dropping pixels to be able to approach a solution. So say a missile hits a barrier - does it drop an edge-pixel or possibly an inner-pixel?

Comment: Regardless, I believe the Space Invader game doesn't actually drop pixels in that way at all. The simpler solution is to have a set of images for a barrier, the first is a complete barrier, and each following image is a stage of it's destruction. Hitting a barrier might not cause immediate effect on the image, but instead you countdown the HP of the barrier - changing the image to the next level every X amount of HP-dmg.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: That's really *really* up to the person implementing it - which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.  *If it were **me*** I'd pick a point within the barrier along the same trajectory as the projectile and just make a new point there - causing a "triangular-ish" indentation in the barrier.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: sure.  that would be an option.  The OP is using vector graphics so I was providing a solution in that vein.  Images are great for raster-based solutions.

Comment: @Sam That's a great solution for pixeldropping. If I understand correctly, you have the top-line of the polygon sorted by X, and when hit, you add a point X,a (a: some number for the Y value) while maintaining order. If the list already has a point with the given X (or a value close enough, depending on how accurate/rough you want the barrier destruction), you lower the Y value of that point instead. I think this is enough to get OP started, if he chooses this approach, and come back if he's struggling with the implementation.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: that would be a decent implementation.  Not what I had in mind, but good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73505/discussion-between-yorye-nathan-and-sam-axe).